Id like to (as efficiently as possible) do all of the labs(assignments with pre-existing code) given to me in codeHS in Replit
I am trying to link an IDE called CodeHS to Replit. I am doing this so all of the data and pre-existing code in CodeHS will be easily and automatically transferred to Replit without having to manually copy and paste everything, or create new file types in Replit. I am trying to code in codeHS using replit effectivley.
I am a complete beginner and I am looking for somebody to specify some things or at least let me know if what I am trying to do is possible. I saw something when I signed up for replit about it being able to make coding easier on websites, it said something like..." host your websites and make programming easier on other platforms" or something like that. Currently my CS class uses an IDE called codeHS. this is a much worse platform to code on than Replit, in fact all of the demo labs(videos guiding us through each assigned lab in our course) feature an experienced programmer guiding us through each lab, but instead of coding the labs on codeHS(like we will have to) he is using Replit. I am wondering if it is possible to link Replit and codeHS so that the code that is already existing in the codeHS labs is almost automatically transfered to the replit platform for coding. This would make it much better for me because I would be able to do all of the labs using Replit which is a much better platform for coding than CodeHS. I will continue experimenting but, please let me know what you can. Any information helps.
